# Parse HTML Content in POI

Tags: html, excel, html-parsing, export-to-excel

I am using POI to create a spreadsheet report, I have html content with `<p>`, `<b/>`, `&nbsp;` etc, how do i parse these html tags in POI?. is there any function in POI which can parse html content?

this is a sample of my POI code:

```
HSSFCell cell = getHSSFCell(mysheet, 5, 1);
cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(htmlContent));
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

POI is not for HTML, it's for MS Office. what you want to use is Xpath for your HTML parsing portion. Xpath is a rabbit hole of it's own, so I won't go into alot of detail about it, but here are some resources for java xpath:

[roseindia tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml)

[javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)

[IBM Xpath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solution would be to use an HTML parser to parse the HTML content and then set the text using POI. I use Jericho HTML Parser. http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

A simple HTML Parsing using jericho:

```
Source source = new Source("The HTML Text");
String parsedHTMLText = source.getTextExtractor().toString();
```